# PHP preg_replace() upper and lowercase difference

Tags: php, preg-replace, uppercase, lowercase, modifier

I have a PHP/Ajax search function that returns all countries which hold the characters entered in a textbox. All these countries are listed and the given characters are marked bold inside the country it's name in the list.

Example
Characters given in textbox: "Af"
Which return **Af** ghanistan and South **Af** rica -
without the space inbetween ofcourse

Now all the countries names in the database ofcourse start with a uppercase letter. But

> preg_replace()

can not find the difference between Upper and lowercase letters. So when i enter "a" in the textbox it will return Afgh **a** nist **a** n notice the first uppercase "A" not made **bold**

Here is the code i am using

```
$display_name = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/", "<b>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['Country_Name']);
$display_url = '';

$output = str_replace('NameReplace', $display_name, $HTML);
$output = str_replace('UrlReplace', $display_url, $output);
echo($output);
```

I can "fix" this problem adding the "/i" modifier to the preg_replace() According to PHP.net it will do the following:

> i (PCRE_CASELESS)
>   If this modifier is set, letters in the pattern match both upper and lower case letters.

This will turn the **bold** characters inside the countries name lowercase or uppercase according to the characters inside the textbox

example:
Characters given in textbox: "A" will return "**A** fgh **A** nist **A** n"
while "a" will return "**a** fgh **a** nist **a** n" again please ignore the white space.

How can i make it that when i enter: "a"
it will return "**A** fgh **a** nist **a** n" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$display_name = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/", "<b>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['Country_Name']);
```

to this:

```
$display_name = preg_replace("/(" . $search_string . ")/i", '<b>$1</b>', $result['Country_Name']);
```

Comment: Please read my entire question. As i have tried this and this poses a problem i do not know how to fix.

Comment: @Krijn van der Burg Sorry i forgot something, i have updated my answer. Try it now.

Comment: I edited it a second time, the () should be behind and before the slash /.

Comment: I tested this and can not see how this works. since $1 is nothing? this returns a error " syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable etc etc."

Comment: Updated again. And now?

Comment: It does not create a error. but it does make the entire country name bold as in. given characters "Afgh" returns **Afghanistan**

Comment: Please try again. There must be single quotes not double. My mistake.

Comment: This works flawless, but i can't understand what you did, could you explain to me what exactly happens with the () braces and the $1 added? I rather learn than get answers. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok... I don't know how it exactly works technically, but i will try to explain it the best way i can... Everything you put in () inside the expression can be accessed in the second parameter of `preg_replace(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3)` with $1, $2... Example: `preg_replace("@(a)(b)(c)@i", '$3$1$2', $string)` would return `cab`. But note that `$3$1$2` must be inside single quotes (' ')! If you put them inside double quotes (" ") it work work. What's inside the first `()` can be accessed in the second parameter with `$1`, what's inside the second `()` is `$2`, and so on...

Comment: That actually makes sense to me. Thanks a lot for explaining that means more to me than the answer. I think i understand the purpose and usage but i will do some more research on the subject trying to see if i/we missed anything. Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: I haven't coded PHP for a while now, had projects in C#, but some PHP projects are waiting for me in the upcoming months, so that this is good exercise for me. :)

Comment: @Krijn van der Burg Check out this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm for more on regex (regular expressio) in php.

Comment: By using parentheses within a regular expression you create a subpattern, which you can later access with a so called backreference. A backreference points to that subpattern by addressing it with a number that depends on the order in which the subpatterns were defined. `$0` (or `\\0`) refers to the whole pattern (the entire regular expression). Just thought I would add some technical terms to the discussion so that you can look them up easily for more information :)

Comment: @rhino +1 for words `subpattern` and `backreference`. Is useful when searching. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo preg_replace("/a/i", "<b>\1</b>", "Afghanistan");
```

*Outputs in HTML*:

**A** fgh **a** nist **a** n

Comment: Thank you for trying to helping but somebody else beat you to it and solved my question and this isn't what i was seeking for. But thank you very much!